# How can I insert text after a certain string is found?

Tags: regex, bash

I have multiple dates I'm working with in a csv. They are all on separate lines. They are represented by

```
219, 5/15/20, PM 
74, 5/16/20, PM
1492, 5/17/20, PM
```

How can I use bash to replace 20 with 2020 or just add another 20 next to the original 20 so it looks like this:

```
219, 5/15/2020, PM
74, 5/16/2020, PM
1492, 5/17/2020, PM
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This seems a direct `/20,` replacement with `/2020,`, did you try it?

Comment: How do you do it @WiktorStribiżew using Bash is the question. I'm new to Bash, sorry haha

Comment: If it is a file, use `sed`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, something like ```sed -i -e 's#/20,#/2020,#g' filename.csv``` will do the job.

Comment: It worked out! Thanks, fellas!

Comment: That comment was supposed to be directed to @TrentXavier instead. Sorry, Wiktor. :-)